# How to optimize recursive function calls and inner loops in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, tree

I want to find all the parents of a particular child from a dataframe. My current code takes more than 20 seconds to compile for a 3000 datapoint dataset. I figured it is because of the recursive function calls and loops I have used. Can you help me optimise the program?

I've tried to search for the parent of the child node, print it and assume it as a child. Then recursively find it's parent and so on until all parents are found exhaustively.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'parent_name': 
    ["Car","Tyre","Tyre","Rubber","Nylon","Nylon","Trees","Trees"],
    'child_name': ["Tyre","Rubber","Nylon","Trees","Chemicals","Man-made","Leaves","Stems"]
    }
)
```

## Define a function using all these to find all parent nodes

```
def get_parent_list(node_id):

    list_of_parents = []  

#define a function to find parent_names for all child_names   
    def find_parent(node_id):

       parent_names = df.loc[df["child_name"].isin([node_id]),"parent_name"]

       for parent_name in parent_names:
          list_of_parents.append(parent_name)
          find_parent(parent_name)

       find_parent(node_id)
       return list_of_parents

  df["list_of_parents"] = df["child_name"].apply(get_parent_list)
```

## I would store the output received as a separate column on the dataframe

### After this I would just do a search in the dataframe for user input and display the corresponding list of parents column as output

OutPut expected :

if user gives : "Trees" as input

output :
Trees : Rubber, tyre, car

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Answer (score 1):

Most natural here is to use a tree data structure, which will have linear query time. Though I'm surprised your approach was that slow, as 3000 datapoints is not huge.

```
import pandas as pd
from treelib import Tree

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "parent_name":
            ["Car", "Tyre", "Tyre", "Rubber", "Nylon", "Nylon", "Trees", "Trees"],
        "child_name": ["Tyre", "Rubber", "Nylon", "Trees", "Chemicals", "Man-made", "Leaves", "Stems"]
    }
)

tree = Tree()
tree.create_node(df["parent_name"][0], df["parent_name"][0])  # root
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    tree.create_node(row["child_name"], row["child_name"], parent=row["parent_name"])
tree.show()

def find_parents(child_name):
    child = tree[child_name]
    parent_names = []
    while child.bpointer is not None:
        parent = tree[child.bpointer]
        parent_names.append(parent.identifier)
        child = parent

    return parent_names


print(find_parents("Trees"))
df["list_of_parents"] = df["child_name"].apply(find_parents)
```

Note : if you modify the dataframe you'll have to recreate the tree before calling the "find_parents" function again. If you modify the dataframe regularly you may choose to recreate the tree inside the find_parents function.

EDIT :  Hi @AkshayKannan , sorry for the late response. Since some nodes may have multiple parents, the proper structure to use here is not a Tree but a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG). The following should work (I added a row ("Nylon","Leaves") to test the multiple parent case)

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "parent_name":
            ["Car", "Tyre", "Tyre", "Rubber", "Nylon", "Nylon", "Trees", "Trees", "Nylon"],
        "child_name": ["Tyre", "Rubber", "Nylon", "Trees", "Chemicals", "Man-made", "Leaves", "Stems", "Leaves"]
    }
)

G = nx.DiGraph()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(row["child_name"], row["parent_name"])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)


def find_parents(child_name):
    return list(nx.descendants(G, child_name))


print(find_parents("Car"))
print(find_parents("Chemicals"))
print(find_parents("Leaves"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @brunoob! This worked for me for the example I had given. It throws a "DuplicatedNodeIdError: Can't create node with ID" error for the original 3000 point file I use. I'm not familiar with the treelib library. Some of my nodes have multiple parents. Can you help me out here?